# How to get attribute name from the widget in yii 1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I used widget in my web application to upload files. In my view file, I used following widget code:

```
<?= $this->widget('application.components.FileUploadWidget',array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'attribute'=>'f_5',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'form-control')
            ),true) ?>
```

I could not retrieve name of the uploaded file.How can I get the name of the uploaded file from the widget?(For example, if I upload file called image.jpg, I will be able to get  image.jpg name itself )

Answer (score 0):

Try to print this

```
public function actionUpload()
{
    $model= new YourModel();
    if(isset($_POST['YourModel']))
    {
        $image = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('f_5');

    echo "<pre>";print_r($image);
    }
```

Comment: I am not using CUploadFile